# How can I host my NextJS website on Winhost which supports IISnode?

Tags: reactjs, iis, next.js, hosting, iisnode

Recently I developed a website using NextJS with some features like ISR and API Routes. Unfortunately, I purchased a hosting service called **Winhost** that is not especially for NextJS and only supports IISnode.

So, is there a way I can host my NextJS website without static exporting and retaining all the features?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day a NextJS application on the server side is a NodeJS application, follow the steps here

1. https://support.winhost.com/kb/a1534/node_js.aspx
2. Make sure you select the right node version with your NextJS application - i.e downloading the right `node.exe`
3. The mapping file seems to be important so nodejs apps are executed by IISNode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```